# Насколько сейчас можно/реально использовать Webworkers?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webworkers, pwa

Я сейчас делаю сайт на сервере ASP.NET Core 2, на клиенте Vue.js
Пробовал использовать Vue CLi 3 для создания макета проекта и там в настройках обнаружилась опция Progressive Web Applications. Прочитал по этой теме, и понял, что идея то собственно классная. Позволить приложениям по максимуму работать offline. Как я понимаю для этого используется webworkers. И собственно вопрос.
Насколько сейчас уже можно использовать эту технологию, в купе с indexedDb?

Она уже ready for production, или скорее на этапе первой притирки и подгонки / тестирования.

Я уже не один раз сталкивался с проблемой, когда сразу начинал использовать новые технологии, а они были ещё сырые, в результате куча сил тратилось на сложности вызванные неотработанностью и багливостью технологии. Сейчас нет желания попадать в эту ситуацию, отсюда и вопрос.

В прошлом году мониторил эту тему, тогда вроде это всё было на стадии только начала или бета версии, как я понял.

Comment: ну если посмотреть webworkers - не такая уж новая технология ей уже не год и не два

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=webworkers  - 93%

Comment: webworkers - да, pwa - еще нет

Comment: @DiDex а можно на основе webworkers сделать так что бы реально контент на сайте кэшировался на клиенте. Сами PWA для меня не особенно актуальны, ну и раз они ещё нет, то обойдусь и без этого (возможно). Но вот доступность для сайта offline для моего проекта будет очень большим бонусом. Особенно было бы интересно в связке именно с vue.js.

Comment: На данный момент при поиске Vue.js + Webworkers почти ничего найти даже не получается.

Comment: у меня статика с помощь манифеста хорошо кешируется. http://htmlbook.ru/html/html/manifest Правда, в последней версии Хрома отключили его поддержку для http

Comment: @Дмытрык  хм... а разве статику сам браузер не кэширует по умолчанию? Я имею ввиду картинки, скрипты, стили... Или ты имеешь ввиду какие-то части html кода?

Comment: Чтобы браузер "сам" кешировал, сервер должен установить соответствующие заголовки...но это я узнал потом). А изначально, поиск Гугла привел меня к манифесту. И я был им доволен. Свой сайт мог загрузить даже без подключения к инету. Но т.к. он у меня на http, сейчас это не работает. И кстати, вот что Chrome пишет по этому поводу (в консоли сообщение)  "Application Cache is restricted to secure contexts. Please consider migrating your application to HTTPS, and eventually shifting over to Service Workers. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details"